# How to prevent DatePicker scrolling into past dates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker

I have a DatePicker that Looks like this:

[image]

And Im setting Notifications from the selected date from the DatePicker, and Its obvious that I dont need the past dates, how can I hide them? I tried something that I found in other question but didnt work, looks like this:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
    [self.DatePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[picker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
```

OR Try This code

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
 NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
 NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
 [comps setYear:30];
 NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
 [comps setYear:-30];
 NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

 [datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
 [datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

It will works for you hopefully.

Comment: You are Welcome.Thats Great :) Kindly upvote my answer so it will also may helps others. Thanks.